# How can I get my JS to reload when other div elements are loaded in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some script that says if a word matches "Remote", make it's colour green.

```js
$('ul li:last-child:contains("Remote")').css('color', '#40b771');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jobcontent">
  <h4>{{ job.title}}</h4>
  <ul class="namelist">
    {% if job.company.count() %}
    <li>{{ job.company.one().title }}</li>{% endif %} {% if job.location %}
    <li>{{ job.location }}</li>{% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now if you take a look at https://www.perkk.co/, you will see that it has made them green but if you apply a filter, which would show a "Remote" post, the green disappears. So I need to somehow call the JS again when the results are loaded.

Comment: Is it a requirement that it gets done by JS? 
You could archieve that by adding that jquery code directly at the css: ul.namelist li:last-child:contains("Remote") { color: #40b771; }

Comment: Hey! No it is not a requirement but doing purely with CSS does't appear to be working :(

Comment: @karran Since when does CSS have a pseudo selector `:contains`? I'd assume that's a pure jQuery feature. Please leave a link with reference for that pseudo selector.

Comment: Sorry, @connexo and elliot-james. Contains really is just a jquery selector :sweat-smile: I tried to answer, if it does not work, please ping me to fix that up.

Comment: @ElliotJames /\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably one way of doing that. By creating a function and triggering it on div changes. You could also add the colorize function to the filter buttons click.

```js
const colorizeRemotes = () => $('ul li:last-child:contains("Remote")').css('color', '#40b771');
colorizeRemotes();
$('.job-container-12').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", colorizeRemotes);

$('#tst').on('click', () => {
$('.job-container-12').html(`
<div class="jobcontent">
  <h4>job 1</h4>
  <ul class="namelist">
    <li>test title</li>
    <li>Remote</li>
  </ul>
</div>`)});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="job-container-12">
<div class="jobcontent">
  <h4>job 1</h4>
  <ul class="namelist">
    <li>job 1</li>
    <li>Remote</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="jobcontent">
  <h4>job 2</h4>
  <ul class="namelist">
    <li>test title</li>
    <li>wow</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
<button id="tst">edit</button>
```